# Compress multiple jpeg files together in C#

Tags: c#, compression, gzip, jpeg, tar

I was trying compress jpeg files (say 16 files) together using C#. I did successfully created a tar file and finally a tar.gz (using  C# GZipStream class). But the problem with my solution is that the gzip pass increased for 37% the size of the tar file (so a compression ratio of 137%). I tried to manually compress the files together using winrar and it gave me a reduction of 10% in the size (compress ratio of 90%).

I believe that my problem is with GZipStream. I think I should go for another kind of compression (or compressor?!), do you have any idea/suggestion of compression to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework's compression routines don't always go a great job.

I would recommend trying [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to compress this.  My experience is that the compression (even Gzip) there is much closer to other software, and far smaller than the framework classes.  This is also nice in that it requires nearly no code changes from the framework's `GzipStream` class if you want to use their `GzipStream` implementation.

Comment: Using your solution, I'm getting a 91% compress ratio with my 16 files. Thank you!